# samuelthomas2774 / android-tv-homekit, Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, gradle

I've been trying to compile this .apk for "samuelthomas277/android-tv-homekit" and I've been stuck on many problems that I kinda managed solve before, but now I'm stuck again at this message from gradle: "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."
> When I try to build in Android Studio, the same happens but it also says "cannot find symbol class io.github.hapjava.HomekitCharacteristicChangeCallback"

```
import io.github.hapjava.HomekitCharacteristicChangeCallback;
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me to solve this! :)

Comment: Why not file an issue on GitHub, where you have obtained the broken code from? And also, a quick search there instantly turned up the required dependency: https://github.com/hap-java/HAP-Java

Comment: Provide full error logs.